# Asus specific utilities

Tags: google-chrome, drivers, motherboard

I just bought the new HW for my home PC. On the DVD with MotherBoard drivers I see a lot of different drivers itself and a lot of different utilities:

- norton antivirus
- Google Chrome
- WinZip
- a lot of others...

Is there any value to install software distributed by Asus? Would Asus-provided Chrome better than just usual one? Same for other utilities...

What is a purpose to distribute all of them?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

This is purely trade agreements between Asus and Google, Norton or other companies. Nothing better has been added, just the same old software. Maybe Asus considere that Chrome could be usefull to it's customers, because Internet Explorer is famous for being a pain.

Though, I believe these software aren't in the box because they are the best one you can find but only because some software editors made agreements with Asus. Most of the people will keep software that were in the box, so it's a valuable thing, not for the user, but for the software editor itself...